# how to implement connection timeout in vert.x socket server?

Tags: netty, vert.x

I am working on a project using vert.x. In this project, I want to implement a function: when a client sends nothing in 15 seconds, server will mark that connection as unused and release it.

I found this post saying hwo to implement this in Netty: [Setting socket timeout on netty channel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3726696/setting-socket-timeout-on-netty-channel).

However, is there a simple way to implement this in vert.x? Or is there a way I could access channels used by the socket server I created? It seems that there is no simple to access the netty objects used in socket server.

Comment: I'm not that familiar with vertx but could you use vertx.setTimer? Every time a packet is received you cancel the timer and create a new one.

Comment: But I want to close the socket once the timer is timeout, just like what was done in that post: ctx.getChannel().close(). Actually, I thought your way, using vertx.setTimer, but if there are many sockets, one timer could not work well with them, :(

Comment: Can't your verticle register a connect handler, then when you handle the connect event you create a handler that is registered for, and handles both socket and timer events, and maintains a reference to the socket. When the timer fires you close the socket? I suspect under the surface the timer is indeed a single timer instance that handlers all timers for that particular event loop. This wouldn't seem that different to sharing a HashWheelTimer between multiple pipelines in netty - which is what the link referenced is doing.

Comment: Thanks, johnstlr. I think I get what you mean. After rechecking the vertx document, I find I have some misunderstanding about timer in vertx, :). Then I try to implement a simple example, please see below. Your point is very helpfule.

Comment: In 3.0.0 version, I found HttpServerOptions setIdleTimeout(int idleTimeout)

Answer (score 3):

This is a simple example showing how to implement a connection management in vertx: if clients close or crash, the corresponding sockets on server side will be closed too.

In this example, if there is no data from one connection in 10s, server will close that connection directly.

### client.groovy

```
vertx.setTimer(1000){ timerID ->
    vertx.createNetClient().connect(1234, "localhost") { socket ->
        socket.dataHandler { buffer ->
            println buffer
        }

        socket.closedHandler {
            println "I closed!"
        }

        socket << "$timerID"
    }    
}

vertx.setTimer(5000){ timerID ->
    vertx.createNetClient().connect(1234, "localhost") { socket ->
        socket.dataHandler { buffer ->
            println buffer
        }

        socket.closedHandler {
            println "I closed!"
        }

        def id = timerID
        vertx.setPeriodic(1000){
            socket << "$id"
        }
    }    
}

vertx.setTimer(10000){ timerID ->
    vertx.createNetClient().connect(1234, "localhost") { socket ->
        socket.dataHandler { buffer ->
            println buffer
        }

        socket.closedHandler {
            println "I closed!"
        }

        socket << "$timerID"
    }    
}
```

### server.groovy

```
import org.vertx.java.core.net.NetSocket
import java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap

socketMap = new ConcurrentHashMap<NetSocket, String>()
liveConnections = new ConcurrentHashMap<String, Boolean>()

vertx.createNetServer().connectHandler{ socket ->
    socket.dataHandler { buffer ->
        socket << buffer
        if(!socketMap.get(socket)){
            register(socket, "${buffer}")
        }else{
            liveConnections.put(socketMap.get(socket), true)
        }

    }

    socket.closedHandler {
        def id = socketMap.get(socket)
        socketMap.remove(socket)
        println "Connection #$id closed!"
        println "Number of clients: ${socketMap.size()}"
    }

    socket.exceptionHandler {
        if(!socketMap.size()){
            return
        }

        def id = socketMap.get(socket)
        socketMap.remove(socket)
        println "Connection #$id got exception, closed!"
        println "Number of clients: ${socketMap.size()}"
        socket.close()
    }
}.listen(1234)

void register(socket,id){
    socketMap.put(socket, id)
    liveConnections.put(id, false)
    println "Connection #$id registered!"
}

vertx.setPeriodic(10000){
    socketMap.each{ item ->
        if(!liveConnections.get(item.value)){
            item.key.close()
        }
        liveConnections.put(item.value, false)
        println "Number of clients: ${socketMap.size()}"
    }
}
```

If you have better ideas, please let me know it, :)